# Angular Ngx Charts not increasing width

Tags: css, angular, ngx-charts

I have a basic stacked bar chart using the angular framework Ngx Charts and I would like the chars to grow horizontally when the parent div expands. I am using angular flex to align a couple of cards next to each other in a row and then once the screen gets smaller each card should take up 100% width of the screen and each card has 1 graph in it. My current code is this:

```
                <div
                    *ngIf="data.length > 0"
                    fxLayout="row"
                    fxLayout.lt-md="column"
                    fxLayoutGap="5px"
                  >
                    <mat-card *ngFor="let array of data"
                              fxFlex="0 1 0"
                              fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 100%"
                              fxFlex.lt-sm="100%"
                              class="max-height"
                    >
                      <mat-card-title style="font-size: 14px">
                        {{array.name}}
                      </mat-card-title>
                        <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
                          <ngx-charts-bar-horizontal-stacked
                            (window:resize)="onResize($event)"
                            [results]="array.data"
                            [showXAxisLabel]="true"
                            [showYAxisLabel]="true"
                            [yAxis]="true"
                            [xAxis]="true"
                            [xAxisTickFormatting]="formatXAxis"
                            (select)="chartClicked($event)"
                          >
                          </ngx-charts-bar-horizontal-stacked>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                  </div>
```

There is no set number of charts so there could be 2 or 10 or more but so far everything works but when the cards grow to 100% of the screen width, the charts still stay small and dont strength horizontally to fit the new card width. I wrapped each chart in a div and set the div to 100% width and height so the charts should auto scale.

Comment: can you please elaborate and possible then attach stackblitz.

Comment: Please add a snippet so that we can start debugging in it rather than creating a new